# referring to associated field in another model in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a table with buyer's name and the fruits that he bought based on that season.

```
class Buyer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fruit = models.ManyToManyField(Fruit, through=‘Season’, related_name=‘seasonal_fruit’)

class Fruit(models.Model):
    fruit_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    
class Season(models.Model):
    season = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The above code throws the following error:

> app.Season: The model is used as an intermediate model by 'app.Buyer.fruit', but
> it does not have a foreign key to 'Buyer' or 'Fruit'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a [**`through=…`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through), then that model needs two `ForeignKey`s: one to the "source" model, and one to the `Target` model, since a `ManyToManyField` is always a model (sometimes an implicit) one that has two `ForeignKey`s to link two other models together: it is implemented as a [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

```
class Season(models.Model):
    season = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```